# Concept of python slicing method

Tags: python, slice

I have below list

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to understand below 
result :-

```
>>> l1
[4:8:-2]
```

Please explain result of above slicing.

Answer (score 1):

slicing is `[start:stop:step]` do like this,
When you are steping it from backward then you have to take index from back,

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> l1[8:4:-2]
[9, 7]
```

You are asking to start from index `4` till index `8` by step `-2`, so you are asking to get index `8` and `6` and avoiding index `4`.

Comment: @lbney Hasan, because you are asking from index `4` to `8` by negative count, what you are doing by giving `step = -2`, start from for `4`, then `4-2`, `2-2` **(-2 is stepping)**, till `8th` index. Now think how it will reach to 8th index.

Comment: if it will start from 4 index then first values should be return 4 index values is 5 then it will check 4-2 2-2 up 8th. Why result is []

Comment: @lbney Hasan python checks first the slicing you are applying, complete statement will parse, and here parsing is wrong, that's why it is thrwoing a vacant list.

Comment: Thanks Vishnu .Now i understand .

Comment: @lbney Hasan If you are seeing any correct mark option at this page then click on it.